# Связь таблицы с моделью Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Разбираюсь с фреймворком Laravel. Такой вопрос:
Создал модель "Category" через артизан и создал таблицу "Categories" через миграцию.
Добавил пару строк, вывел - все работает. Вопрос, каким образом Laravel знает что к модели привязанна именно это таблица, если я не указывал в ручную свойство "table" в классе модели? Где в файлах фреймворка указана эта связь?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

все же [документировано](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names)

> **By convention**, the "snake case", **plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified**. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the `Flight` model stores records in the `flights` table, while an `AirTrafficController` model would store records in an `air_traffic_controllers` table.

в общем-то так примерно все фреймворки поступают нынче

относительно кода - по иерархии наследования в `Model` перейдите:

```
   /**
     * Get the table associated with the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Существует соглашение о именовании, в котором рекомендуется называть модели единственном числе (например, Post, Category)
А таблицы в бд исходя из функции getTable()

Вы всегда можете указать любую другую или таблицу через свойство
protected $table = 'table_name'; в модели